# how to retrieve the difference between the two given dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to find the Longest Booking ID for the given two dates and Costliest Booking ID for the given cost.

Here we have the  13 days difference so we are getting the longest booking id as 1.

what are the approach to archive this using sql query.

[image]

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: dont use image give it as text

Comment: i tried with : SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2017/08/25', '2017/08/28') AS DateDiff;  but i'm not able to get the max count of that

Comment: @AVINASHM the costliest booking id will be 1 14*3000=42000 the data given is wrong i reckon

Comment: What is the datatype for StartDate and EndDate columns ?

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
(SELECT 'Total Booking Count' AS Label, COUNT(*) AS Value FROM bookings)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Longest Booking Id', booking_id FROM bookings ORDER BY DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate) DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Costliest Booking Id', booking_id FROM bookings ORDER BY (tariff*DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate)) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data
  as (select *
            ,row_number() over(order by datediff(dd,end_date,start_date) desc) as rnk_time
            ,row_number() over(order by tarrif desc) as rnk_cost
            ,count(*) over(partition by 1) as tot_cnt
        from your_table
     )
select 'Total Booking count',tot_cnt
 from data 
where rnk_time=1
union all
select 'Longest Booking id',booking_id
 from data 
where rnk_time=1
union all
select 'Costliest Booking id',booking_id
 from data 
where rnk_cost=1
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER requires a recent MySQL version, you must clarify what OP is using.